# How to install snakemake 4.3.X?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, snakemake

I need to install `snakemake 4.3.X (better 4.3.1)`, which is supported by `python 3.5` and `python 3.6`.

I've downloaded:

`Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`,
`Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh`,
`Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh`

from
https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

and installed snakemake separately by using command:

```
./conda install -c bioconda snakemake
```

the snakemake installed for each are all `version 3.13.1`.

Which Anaconda is the proper one for installing `snakemake 4.3.X (better 4.3.1)` ?

Or are there some other better ways to install `snakemake 4.3.X`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your use case, **you should not install Anaconda**. Instead, follow [the recommendation of Bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html) (the repository that hosts the `snakemake` package), and install [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

Next, set up your channel priorities:

```bash
conda config --add channels defaults
conda config --add channels bioconda
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Update the **base** Conda

```bash
conda update -n base conda
```

Then create a new environment for the Snakemake version you require:

```bash
conda create -n snakemake_4_3_1 snakemake=4.3.1
```

In general, try to leave the **base** environment alone (other than updating `conda`), and whenever you need something for a particular task or project, create a new environment for it.

Comment: @Emily it looks like you didn't cleanly uninstall Anaconda. You need to ensure that it is completely off your system, including cleaning up any edits it made to .bashrc and other hidden files in your user directory. You should not have to hunt for the `snakemake`. Activating the environment puts it on PATH no matter where you are.

Comment: @Emily no it will not be in `miniconda3/bin`, but instead will install to the environment folder, in this case `miniconda3/envs/snakemake_4_3_1/bin`. But the point of Conda environments is that you never need to go there manually. PATH is an environment variable that tells the shell where to search for commands, and when one runs `conda activate snakemake_4_3_1`, Conda will automatically add that bin folder to PATH. You can check with `which snakemake` after activation.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. (1) I thought I could install different versions of Anaconda/Miniconda and they work independent to each other. Now I feel you need to completely delete all the old versions if you want to install a new one, correct? (2) The miniconda3 and the following tools (e.g.snakemake) were installed to my /home/ directory by default, if I want to install miniconda/anaconda to the shared directory of my department, how can I manage it?

Comment: @Emily glad that helped. (1) yes you are correct: only one Conda (mini- or ana-) needs to be installed. (2) have a look at the `pkgs_dirs` and `envs_dirs` configuration options. Those control where the package cache is located and where named environments are created by default. These are questions addressed in documentation and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting the older version of snakemake due to version conflicts with the pre-installed modules that accompany an anaconda installation. The anaconda installers you have used are rather old (2 years), so you should probably try with a [newer version](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh).

This is not guaranteed to work though. it is not about the version of `conda`, but about the pre-installed modules in `base`. Dependencies in the `anaconda` base env can be tricky.
The best solution would be to simply create an environment with the specifications that you need:

```
conda create -n smake -c bioconda snakemake=4.3.1
conda activate smake
```

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the newer version, however, it shows information like:   ##
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done//
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.//
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done//
Solving environment: | 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages//
UnsatisfiableError: 
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
## it seems the newer versions don't support older snakemake

Comment: @Emily it worked for me with `conda create -n smake -c bioconda snakemake=4.3.1 python=3.5`. I am positive you do not have to install from source.

Comment: @Emily you can install snakemake and python in the same env, with defined versions. Just use the exact command I placed above. If that does not work, try turning off strict channel priority: `conda config --set channel_priority false`

Comment: `anaconda3/pkgs` is not a directory where pkgs are installed to, it is a cache where things are extracted to after downloading. If the installation was succesfull, you should be able to just run `snakemake`, or alternatively, locate it in the `anaconda3/envs/myenv` folder

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI there are many newer versions, and we are currently at 5.30.1. Anyhow, you should use:

```
conda install -c bioconda snakemake=4.3.1
```

But it is probably best to make a new environment.

Take a look at [conda: manage environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) for more info about how to install different environments. Possibly you also have to [add](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html) `conda-forge` as a channel:

```
conda config --add channels bioconda
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```